# Nunjucks import all macro without define a name with gulp

Tags: nunjucks

We need to define a name when import a macro like this

```
{% import "macros/btn.njk" as i_dont_want_to_define_this_name %}
```

but i dont wanna to define it, i just want to use my macro name, is it possible?